# How to prevent TFS from ignoring files

Tags: tfs, tfvc, tfignore

In a project I'm working on we check in Ruby with sass in order to compile scss files during the build. I switched to using a local workspace when updating gems so that changes are detected automatically. This works great except for the fact that files for new gems that reside in a bin folder are always ignored.

I have no existing tfignore files so I wonder is there some global ignore list that I could potentially edit or override.

I've tried adding a tfignore file at the root and even at the same level as the bin folder in an effort to force team explorer to stop ignoring those files but have had zero success thus far.

The content of the tfignore file is just one line:

```
!bin
```

How can I get team explorer to detect these changes automatically so I don't have to go through the extra step of finding and adding these files manually?

Comment: Are you using Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) or Git?

Comment: The team project in question is using TFVC.

Answer (score -1):

Bin and Obj folders are never shown in the project and adding files within those directories require some kind of manual step.  If your goal by "not adding them manually" means you don't want to add them through "Source Control Explorer" but would just rather add them while working with a solution and project through "Solution Explorer", then you can click the "Show All Files" icon at the top of VS 2013/2012/2010.

[image]

This will then show you your potential bin/obj folders you may want to add files from:

[image]

Then you just right-click and include them.  Once they're included, when you go to check them in, TFS knows you intend to add them to source control so it will show up in the Team Explorer pending changes window, if you are checking in from a higher-level in tree hierarchy.  If you're not, then you can go to the "Excluded Changes" to find pending change you want to include in your final change.

If items are being excluded in anyway, try removing the .tfignore files and depending on your version of Visual Studio and settings, you may also be excluding your files through options such as this:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\AddOptions

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think you fully understand the crux of the problem. Ruby is used during our build via a xcopy deployment and is therefore checked in to TFS. The bin folder in question is already under source control. I want to update Ruby gems and have those changes picked up automatically. Using a local workspace does the trick except that the bin folder is automatically ignored and I was unable to get a tfignore file working that would prevent that from happening.